# Mongodb: how to populate a schema referenced in my schema through my api

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, express, schema

I want to edit my Api to be able to populate a referenced schema.
here is my schema:

```js
export const taskSchema = new Schema ({
    user:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    project: { 
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    issue: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    records : [{
   
        _domain: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'TaskDomains'
        },
        time: {
            type:Number
        }
    
    }],
    
   
    dateCreated: {
     
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

my taskDomain schema :

```js
export const TaskDomains = new Schema ({
    label:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

});
```

how can I edit the following post method to populate the referenced TaskDomain schema.
here is my method:

```js
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {taskSchema,TaskDomains} from '../models/tasks.model';
import {Request, Response} from 'express';

const Task = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
const domain = mongoose.model('domain', TaskDomains);
export class taskController{
public addNewTask (req: Request, res:Response){
        let newTask = new Task();
        newTask.user = req.body.user;
        newTask.project = req.body.project;
        newTask.issue = req.body.issue;
        newTask.title = req.body.title;
        newTask.dateCreated = req.body.dateCreated;
        newTask.records = new domain(req.body._domain);
        newTask.records = new domain(req.body._domain.label);
        newTask.records = req.body.time;

        newTask.save((err, task)=>{
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(task);
        });
    }
    }
```

I need help editing the post method. I have been trying different ways but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current apporach is somewhat wrong, You need to first save the domain document and on successful save you can create the task document.

Try this:

```
public addNewTask (req: Request, res:Response){

    // create the domain document first, before creating the task document, and then store its _id in the task document
    let _domain = new domain(req.body._domain);
    _domain.save((err,_domain)=>{
        let newTask = new Task();
        newTask.user = req.body.user;
        newTask.project = req.body.project;
        newTask.issue = req.body.issue;
        newTask.title = req.body.title;
        newTask.dateCreated = req.body.dateCreated;

        // here you only need to store the _id of the newly created _domain document
        newTask.records = [{
            _domain : _domain._id,
            time : req.body.time
        }]

        newTask.save((err, task)=>{
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
            }
            //if you want populated _domain object in your records array, you can use .populate()
            Task.populate(task,{path : records._domain},(err,task) =>                                 
            {
               res.json(task);
            })
        });
    })
}
```

I am assuming, your request body looks like this :

```
{
    user : "user_name",
    project : "project_name",
    issue : "issue_name",
    title : "title_",
    dateCreated : "date",
    _domain : {
        label : "some_label"
    },
    time : 12345
}
```

Comment: thank you so much , i will try it now and let you know if it works. how do i post the record on postman ?

Comment: i want to try and see if this method works on postman :
how do i fill in the body :
{
   
    "user": "salma",
    "project": "9",
    "issue": "24",
    "title": "task3"
     "records":[
      {
      "label":"test"
      },{"time":40}]
}

Comment: Just try it like this : `{ "user": "salma", "project": "9", "issue": "24", "title": "task3", "_domain" : { "label":"test" },"time":40 }`. If you send the request as you are suggested in your previous comment, you will have to change the code i gave accordingly

Comment: I get the following : {
    "_id": "5c9c5456d5ef022b6db2f88e",
    "records": [
        {
            "_id": "5c9c5456d5ef022b6db2f88f",
            "time": 40
        }
    ],
    "user": "salma",
    "project": "9",
    "issue": "24",
    "title": "task3",
    "__v": 0
} label not posted

Comment: Label is also posted, but since it is a different document (referenced document) , it is saved in domain document, See you have used `type :  Schema.Types.ObjectId` in your schema. If you want to populate domain as well after saving, you need to use `.populate()`. Please read about referenced documents and how to use them in mongoose